# How to align SVG text to left in SVG path?

Tags: svg

I'm having a hard time aligning the text of my SVG to the left. As I adjust the max-height value of it, the text always stays in the middle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 150.2 71" id="3a63"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="m38 70-4.7-16.3H11.1L6.5 70H0L20.5 0h3.3l20.6 70H38Zm77.5 1h-4a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 0 1-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-1.2-5.7V33.7A14.4 14.4 0 0 1 98 28a14.8 14.8 0 0 1 3.1-4.7q2-2 4.7-3.1a14.4 14.4 0 0 1 5.7-1.2h4a14.4 14.4 0 0 1 5.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 0 1 4.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 0 1 1.1 5.7v11.8h-27.4v11.1q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 0 0 1.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 0 0 2.8-1.8q1.2-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4v-3.3l6 1v2a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 0 1-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-5.7 1.2Zm-45.4 0h-4a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 0 1-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-1.2-5.7V0h6v24.2q2-2.4 5-3.8 2.8-1.4 6.2-1.4h1.5a14.4 14.4 0 0 1 5.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 0 1 4.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 0 1 1.1 5.7v22.6a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 0 1-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 0 1-5.7 1.2Zm80.1-1h-6V0h6v70ZM78.8 56.6V33.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 0 0-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 0 0-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-2 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v23.2q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 0 0 1.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 0 0 2.8-1.8q1.1-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4ZM22 15.4l-9.2 32.3h18.8l-9.2-32.3-.2-2.6-.2 2.6Zm102.2 25.4v-7.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 0 0-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 0 0-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-1.9 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v7.4h21.4Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path></symbol>
</svg>

<svg style="max-height:50px; text-align:left;"><use xlink:href="#3a63"></use></svg>
```

I tried using CSS and translate() without success.

Comment: You haven't got any text, you've got some lines that look like letters. If you use actual text i.e. <text>abel</text> you can position it as text.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thank you for that information. I'm trying to avoid using <text> because I don't want to load the font. I'm creating a sprite of fonts and want to just use paths instead to reduce HTTP requests and bandwidth.

Comment: Sure but then you can't use any text CSS properties such as text-align because you don't actually have any text.

Comment: Yup, understood. This will be a static SVG image, so I don't need to adjust anything once it's set.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<symbol>`'s viewBox is actually perfect.

But the new parent `<svg>` containing the **`<use>` element won't inherit the symbol's viewBox automatically**.

**Mnemonic bridge:** styles/properties can (usually) only be inherited **from ancestor to descendant** (e.g parent to child element).

So you need to copy the `viewBox` attribute to the new wrapping `svg`:

##### Example1: Copy `<symbol>` viewBox

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:1em;
  width: auto;
}

p{
font-size:10em;
margin:0;
}

.txt-right{
text-align:right
}

.hidden{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 150.2 71" id="logo">
  <path d="m38 70-4.7-16.3h-22.2l-4.6 16.3h-6.5l20.5-70h3.3l20.6 70h-6.4zm77.5 1h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-22.6a14.4 14.4 0 011.2-5.7 14.8 14.8 0 013.1-4.7q2-2 4.7-3.1a14.4 14.4 0 015.7-1.2h4a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v11.8h-27.4v11.1q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.2-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4v-3.3l6 1v2a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm-45.4 0h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-56.3h6v24.2q2-2.4 5-3.8 2.8-1.4 6.2-1.4h1.5a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v22.6a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm80.1-1h-6v-70h6v70zm-71.4-13.4v-23.2q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-2 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v23.2q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.1-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4zm-56.8-41.2-9.2 32.3h18.8l-9.2-32.3-.2-2.6-.2 2.6zm102.2 25.4v-7.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-1.9 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v7.4h21.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<p>
<svg  viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
  <use href="#logo" />
</svg>
</p>

<p class="txt-right">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
  <use href="#logo" />
</svg>
</p>

<p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200.2 71">
  <use x="50" width="150.2" href="#logo" />
</svg>
</p>
```

Besides, `<use>` elements support `x` and `y` attributes for additional shifting.

#### Why defining a `<symbol>` `viewBox` at all, if we need to apply them anyway to the parent `<svg>` – not very DRY?

Admittedly, you *might* not need a viewBox for all `<symbol>`s – provided you apply the appropriate viewBox to the current svg element instance.

However, it makes a difference, if you need to take advantage of `<use>` elements' capability, to adjust positioning based on their intrinsic viewBox/aspect-ratio via attributes like `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

##### Example 2: symbol with or without `viewBox`

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p{
  margin:1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible;
}

.svg-icon{
  height: 100%;
}

.w240{
  width:240px;
  height:auto;
}


.txt-center{
  text-align:center
}

.txt-right{
  text-align:right
}

code{
  background: #eee;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Thanks for nothing <code>&lt;symbol&gt;</code> <code>viewBox</code>?</h2>
<p>Symbol has <strong>own viewBox:</strong> as well as x and width</p>
<div class="w240">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use x="50%" width="50" href="#logo" />
  </svg>
</div>

<p>Symbol has <strong>no viewBox:</strong> as well as x and width</p>
<div class="w240">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use x="50%" width="20" href="#logo-noViewBox" />
  </svg>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 150.2 71" id="logo">
    <path d="M38 70 l-4.7-16.3h-22.2l-4.6 16.3h-6.5l20.5-70h3.3l20.6 70h-6.4zm77.5 1h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-22.6a14.4 14.4 0 011.2-5.7 14.8 14.8 0 013.1-4.7q2-2 4.7-3.1a14.4 14.4 0 015.7-1.2h4a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v11.8h-27.4v11.1q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.2-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4v-3.3l6 1v2a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm-45.4 0h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-56.3h6v24.2q2-2.4 5-3.8 2.8-1.4 6.2-1.4h1.5a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v22.6a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm80.1-1h-6v-70h6v70zm-71.4-13.4v-23.2q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-2 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v23.2q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.1-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4zm-56.8-41.2-9.2 32.3h18.8l-9.2-32.3-.2-2.6-.2 2.6zm102.2 25.4v-7.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-1.9 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v7.4h21.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>


<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol data-viewBox="0 0 150.2 71" id="logo-noViewBox">
    <path d="M38 70 l-4.7-16.3h-22.2l-4.6 16.3h-6.5l20.5-70h3.3l20.6 70h-6.4zm77.5 1h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-22.6a14.4 14.4 0 011.2-5.7 14.8 14.8 0 013.1-4.7q2-2 4.7-3.1a14.4 14.4 0 015.7-1.2h4a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v11.8h-27.4v11.1q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.2-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4v-3.3l6 1v2a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm-45.4 0h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-56.3h6v24.2q2-2.4 5-3.8 2.8-1.4 6.2-1.4h1.5a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v22.6a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm80.1-1h-6v-70h6v70zm-71.4-13.4v-23.2q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-2 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v23.2q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.1-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4zm-56.8-41.2-9.2 32.3h18.8l-9.2-32.3-.2-2.6-.2 2.6zm102.2 25.4v-7.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-1.9 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v7.4h21.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

#### Explicit `width` and `height` attributes

Responding to the OP's comment:
Quite often (for responsive front-end usage e.g. icons)* it's a better idea to avoid explicit width/height attributes.

As the `viewBox` already defines an aspect ratio – we
usually only need to specify either width or height like `width:100px; height: auto;` or `height:100px; width: auto;`

*(Of course, there are always exceptions)

##### Example 3: no explicit width/height

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
}

.svg-icon {
  height: 100%;
}

.w240 {
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
}

.h50 {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.em5 {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.em5 .svg-icon {
  height: 0.7em;
  width: auto;
}

.txt-center {
  text-align: center
}

.txt-right {
  text-align: right
}

code {
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Adjust to parent div width: 240px</p>
<div class="w240">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use href="#logo" />
  </svg>
</div>

<p>Adjust to parent div height: 100px</p>
<div class="h50">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use href="#logo" />
  </svg>
</div>

<p>Adjust to parent element's font-size: 5em</p>
<p class="em5">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use href="#logo" />
  </svg> Logo
</p>


<p class="txt-center">Adjust to parent element's font-size: 5em - center</p>
<p class="em5 txt-center">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use href="#logo" />
  </svg> Logo
</p>

<p class="txt-right">Adjust to parent element's font-size: 5em - right</p>
<p class="em5 txt-right">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 150.2 71">
    <use href="#logo" />
  </svg> Logo
</p>

<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 150.2 71" id="logo">
    <path d="M38 70 l-4.7-16.3h-22.2l-4.6 16.3h-6.5l20.5-70h3.3l20.6 70h-6.4zm77.5 1h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-22.6a14.4 14.4 0 011.2-5.7 14.8 14.8 0 013.1-4.7q2-2 4.7-3.1a14.4 14.4 0 015.7-1.2h4a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v11.8h-27.4v11.1q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.2-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4v-3.3l6 1v2a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm-45.4 0h-4a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7-1.2 14.8 14.8 0 01-4.7-3.1q-2-2-3.1-4.7a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.2-5.7v-56.3h6v24.2q2-2.4 5-3.8 2.8-1.4 6.2-1.4h1.5a14.4 14.4 0 015.7 1.2 14.8 14.8 0 014.7 3.1q2 2 3.2 4.7a14.4 14.4 0 011.1 5.7v22.6a14.4 14.4 0 01-1.1 5.7 14.8 14.8 0 01-3.2 4.7q-2 2-4.7 3.1a14.4 14.4 0 01-5.7 1.2zm80.1-1h-6v-70h6v70zm-71.4-13.4v-23.2q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-2 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v23.2q0 1.8.7 3.4a8.8 8.8 0 001.9 2.8q1.1 1.2 2.7 1.8 1.6.7 3.4.7h4q1.8 0 3.4-.7a8.8 8.8 0 002.8-1.8q1.1-1.2 1.8-2.8.7-1.6.7-3.4zm-56.8-41.2-9.2 32.3h18.8l-9.2-32.3-.2-2.6-.2 2.6zm102.2 25.4v-7.4q0-1.8-.7-3.4a8.8 8.8 0 00-1.8-2.8q-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.8-1.6-.7-3.4-.7h-4q-1.8 0-3.4.7a8.8 8.8 0 00-2.7 1.8q-1.2 1.2-1.9 2.8-.7 1.6-.7 3.4v7.4h21.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: I added width property to each <symbol> last night based on aspect ratio calculation which worked because the SVG would no longer stretch beyond the width of the content. However, this involved running a script and assigning a width to each symbol individually.

However, your suggestion is a far better approach. Thank You!

Comment: Please check the new examples. The `viewBox`  already contains all valuable aspect-ratio data. Setting explicit width/height usually rather complicates your css layout tasks (e.g. you need more overriding rules)

Answer (score 0):

As Robert says, you have a `<path>` drawing lines, which we read as text.

Preferably you want to change that path, and make it start on the left. But your path contains Absolute notation; so you have to change it to relative with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Easiest in this case is to change the `viewBox` and *cut-off* part of the left side: first value is the X position: `viewBox="120 0 150 71"`

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the detailed response. How can you tell it uses absolute notation? I will try using the cut-off method you mentioned to see how it goes.

Comment: @ArminBusatlic because the path contains capital letters (absolute) rather than lower case letters (relative).

Comment: This is the first time I hear about it. Thanks you for that information!

Comment: I converted it to relative path. Not sure how to make it start from 0,0. I used transform="translate(x,0)" to move the text but I would have to calculate the offset for every font in the sprite. Isn't there a way to set it to draw from 0,0 to mimic left alignment using path?

Comment: the first m is the x y position